# Listen to bootstrap checkbox being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap theme called: Core Admin
http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0135486

This is the code I write:

```
<div class="span6">
    <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" id="Checkbox1" name="userAccessNeeded">
    <label for="icheck1">Needed</label>
</div>
```

And bootstrap generates me this code:

```
<div class="span6">
<div class="icheckbox_flat-aero" style="position: relative;">
    <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" id="Checkbox7" name="userAccessNeeded" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
    <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"></ins>
</div>
<label for="icheck1" class="">Needed</label>
```

This is the result: [image]

So basically it makes a pretty checkbox for me. Each time I click on the checkbox, it will add a `checked` class to the div:

```
 <div class="icheckbox_flat-aero checked" style="position: relative;">
```

So at first I wanted to listen the input field being changed like this

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="userAccessNeeded"]').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {

    }
});
```

But it doesn't actually change the input field, but rather changes the class of `<div>` element.

How could I listen to checkbox being checked?

Comment: Are you sure twitte bootstrap doesnt  add the checked property to your checkbox upon checking it ?

Comment: @dreamweiver yes, I am using the core admin theme, you can see example here and inspect the checkbox element, it only changes class. http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0135486

Comment: but i cant see any checkbox`s in there.

Comment: @dreamweiver sorry, press Forms from the left panel and there are checkboxes

Comment: I guess my approach should be easy and simple comparatively :) anyway with your logic also it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it like this, since I am clicking on a div element, then I must listen click event of that, and then check if the div has class and what is the id of checkbox.

```
 $('.iCheck-helper').click(function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent().get(0);
    var checkboxId = parent .getElementsByTagName('input')[0].id;
    alert(checkboxId);
});
```

Comment: why cant you add a event for the div tag itself,which is reduce the dom searching  for parent element.

Comment: @dreamweiver `<div class="icheckbox_flat-aero" style="position: relative;">` is auto generated by boostrap, so I can't add anything there.

Comment: so what if its generated dynamically, you will trigger that event only after it has been loaded ,so no worries about that :) you need to be in sync with the bootstrap to accomplish your task,else your it will become unstable

Answer (score 11):

```
$('input#Checkbox1').change(function () {
    if ($('input#Checkbox1').is(':checked')) {
        $('input#Checkbox1').addClass('checked');
    } else {
        $('input#Checkbox1').removeClass('checked');
    }
});
```

i solve it that way.

Answer (score 3):

The template looks to be using https://github.com/fronteed/iCheck/, which has callbacks:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="userAccessNeeded"]').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

Or there is also:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="userAccessNeeded"]').iCheck('check', function(){
  alert('Well done, Sir');
});
```

Which should work with a whole range of methods:

```
// change input's state to 'checked'
$('input').iCheck('check');

// remove 'checked' state
$('input').iCheck('uncheck');

// toggle 'checked' state
$('input').iCheck('toggle');

// change input's state to 'disabled'
$('input').iCheck('disable');

// remove 'disabled' state
$('input').iCheck('enable');

// change input's state to 'indeterminate'
$('input').iCheck('indeterminate');

// remove 'indeterminate' state
$('input').iCheck('determinate');

// apply input changes, which were done outside the plugin
$('input').iCheck('update');

// remove all traces of iCheck
$('input').iCheck('destroy');
```

Answer (score 3):

Link to the Documentation: http://fronteed.com/iCheck/

You need to bind to the ifchecked event via

Use on() method to bind them to inputs:

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
  alert(event.type + ' callback');
});
```

this will change the checked state

```
$('input').iCheck('check'); — change input's state to checked
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
jQuery('input.icheck').on('ifChanged', function (event) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just my five cents, if anyone would have the same problem..

I needed the exact checkbox states. Toggle not worked here. This one has done the required state delivery for me:

```
$('.iCheck-helper').click(function () {
    var checkbox = $(this).parent();
    if (checkbox.hasClass('checked')) {
        checkbox.first().addClass('checked');
    } else {
        checkbox.first().removeClass('checked');
    }
        doWhateverAccordingToChoices();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your question and working with bootstrap since the past 1 year, I can definitely say that the checked class being added is not done by bootstrap. Neither is the checked class being added is a property which is built into BS 2.3.*.

Yet for your specific question try the following code.

```
$('.icheck').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

You can get a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hunkyhari/CVJhe/).

**Update 1:**
The Checkbox cannot be styled by color using CSS. Hence, the developer is using insert tag to delete the Checkbox and put in his styling code. In effect, the CSS and JS in the specified theme do the styling by putting in the new stylized code.

Instead you can listed to the click event on the div `icheckbox_flat-aero`.

```
$('.icheckbox_flat-aero').children().on('click',function(){
   alert('checked');
});
```

Check for the example http://jsfiddle.net/hunkyhari/CVJhe/1/

Comment: This does not help me, look how the class changes here, this is the theme I am using: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0135486 . Press on the checkbox and inspect element

Comment: @Jaanus Did the update help?? Are you still stuck?

If you are looking at identifying the check from server side, you may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

@Srihari got it right except the selector. Indeed the `input` isn't modified `onclick`, but the `div` do :

```
$('.icheckbox_flat-aero').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input:checkbox').toggleClass('checked'); // or .find('.icheck').
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey i hope this logic should work for you

**JS CODE:**

```
$('.icheckbox_flat-aero').on('click',function(){ 
     var checkedId=$(this,'input').attr('id');
     alert(checkedId);
});
```

This way a general event is added for all the checkbox`s

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use this:

```
$('input#Checkbox1').on('ifChanged',function() {
   console.log('checked right now');
});
```